# Capture a value inside of a NSLog Result

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

**Editing for clarification**

The userID is generated on the server side, so I don't actually retrieve the userID until after I POST the newly registered username and password. Like so:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSError *error;

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        userName.text, @"userName",
                        password.text, @"password",
                        nil];

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];

NSLog(@"PARAMS = %@", params);

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;

NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:0 error:&error];

NSString *results = json[@"result"];
if ([results isEqualToString:@"ok"])
{
    [self uploadS3Photo];
    NSLog(@"RESULT = %@", responseString);

}
```

}

**End of Edit**

I'm not quite sure how to grab the value userID, and post it back as an `NSMutableString`.

What I get back from the database is this

```
2014-02-23 20:52:48.029 TestData[245923:92c] RESULT = {"result":"ok","userId":26}
```

That number "26", I need to store and then call back to reverse its number, using a method like below.

```
-(NSString *)reverseString:(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableString *reversed = [NSMutableString string];
    NSInteger charIndex = [str length];
    while (charIndex > 0) {
        charIndex--;
        NSRange subRange = NSMakeRange(charIndex, 1);
        [reversed appendString:[str substringWithRange:subRange]];
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Comment: Get it out of the dictionary you're printing. This has nothing to do with NSLog.

Comment: (I was wrong -- see below) "RESULT" is an NSDictionary from somewhere.  The value of "userid" in the dictionary is an NSNumber.  None of these is a NSString, so you have me confused.

Comment: Well, actually no.  "RESULT" is a JSON string.  You need to decode the JSON through NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: (If you don't know what JSON is you're probably in over your head, but see json.org.)

Comment: I edited my question for a better understanding. Sorry about that!

Comment: So you got `result` back from the server, and have already decoded it into the `json` dictionary.  You even fetched "result" out of the dictionary.  And you can't figure out how to fetch "userId"????  (Keep in mind that the value of "userId" will be an NSNumber.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh--

```
NSInteger userId = json[@"userId"].integerValue;
```

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry. Its been a stressful day today. Cannot even think correctly. I appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

You have a string with JSON content. To get the number from it you have to use `NSJSONSerialization`.

Here is how to do it:

```
NSData *data = [yourJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSNumber *myNumber = dict[@"RESULT"][@"userId"];
```

Then you can convert it to string:

```
NSString *stringWithNumber = [myNumber stringValue];
```

Comment: `{"result":"ok","userId":26}` is not a NSDictionary.

Comment: Actually, no.  It's JSON.

Comment: Yeap, word! you are right!